# How to Open a Form in Side of Another form in ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

browsing the web, I saw a lot of sites that open a child-page in the side of the parent page. a good example of this is notion.sa (see the attached picture).

I wonder how can i make this in ASP.Net, Html, and css. it is easy to open a dialoguebox-Like form in the center of the parent. but i want a child-form in which it stick in the right-side or left-side all along the edge of the parent.

is there any css or js library that can perform this easily?

thanks in advance....[image]

I browsed google and youtube to find something helpful in this, but all my tries went in vain